# Flutter Test: Look for a widget inside of another widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, widget-test-flutter

I am looking for the way to see that the widget I have found in the test, has certain text inside. In my case I want to look for the specific text not inside the complete `RadioButtonGroup` but inside of the found `ElevatedButton` --> `firstButton`. Is it possible?

```
 testWidgets('Horizontal Radio Group builds a Row', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
        Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: simpleRadio
        ));

    expect(find.byType(Row), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.byType(Column), findsNothing);
    var optionButtons = find.byType(ElevatedButton);
    expect(optionButtons, findsNWidgets(2));
    ElevatedButton firstButton = tester.firstWidget(optionButtons);
    
  });
```

Looking for something like: `expect(firstButton.findByText('bla'), findsOneWidget);`

Answer (score 2):

One can use `Finder#descendant`, exemplified in its doc

```
    expect(find.descendant(
            of: find.widgetWithText(Row, 'label_1'),
            matching: find.text('value_1')), findsOneWidget);
```

Comment: what is label_1 here ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [widgetWithText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/CommonFinders/widgetWithText.html). This'll find a widget of `widgetType` that has a `Text` descendant with the given text.

So for your example, something like:

```
expect(find.widgetWithText(ElevatedButton, 'bla'), findsOneWidget);
```